# Azure Pricing Calculator for Databricks: DBUs are not matching

Tags: azure

I am using the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) and try to asses my `Databricks` costs.

I have a Datatbricks service up and running which I use to asses my calculation. In the Cluster Summary (in databricks), it shows me, that `5-8 DBU/h` will be consumed. In the pricing calculator, the predefined DBU/h are significantly lower (`1.5 DBU/h`). Why are the two numbers different?
I checked:

- Region
- Tier
- Cluster Type

Comment: Hi @user3579222, BDU/h depends on he instance you are using. do you see same instace type but different dbu/h ?

Comment: yes: thats the weird thing!!